# FreeSwitch mod_python(or any other modules) installation on CentOs 7

Tags: centos7, python-module, freeswitch

All the FreeSwitch documentations are given assuming you have installed Debian. So for CentOs or any RHEL distribution users are having a problem.

When I tried to follow the  mod_python documentation given by FreeSwitch, I am getting errors.
Now, How can I install mod_python or any other modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CentOs for installing any software, search the yum repo.

Like here,
I ran

`yum search freeswitch`

I got all the FreeSwitch modules. Now find your required modules and install.

Like here for `mod_python` module, I typed

`yum install freeswitch-python.x86_64`

Now, type  `cd /etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/` and edit modules.conf.xml

Add `<load module="mod_python"/>` and save the file and exit.
Now, use `fs_cli` command and type `reloadxml`.

After this restart your linux system and again type `fs_cli` and type `module_exists mod_python`.

This should show true. If so, that means mod_python installation is successful.